# Mouse freezes on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: keyboard, mouse, 17.10, freeze

My mouse keeps freezing every few seconds. It is mostly the movement but sometimes the buttons and occasionally the keyboard. When both stop working my only recourse is a hard reset.

I have run `dmesg` and the only negative statements I can see are:

```
[    0.092312] ACPI Error: [_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PXSX] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/dswload2-191)
[    0.092316] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20170531/psobject-252)
[    0.092317] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.RP04.PXSX, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/psparse-550)
[    0.092506] ACPI Error: [_SB_.PCI0.RP09.PXSX] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/dswload2-191)
[    0.092508] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20170531/psobject-252)
[    0.092510] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.RP08.PXSX, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170531/psparse-550)


[    0.793008] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e4(Receiver ID)
[    0.793009] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:   device [8086:a294] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[    0.793011] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)


[    3.438603] NVRM: Your system is not currently configured to drive a VGA console
               on the primary VGA device. The NVIDIA Linux graphics driver
               requires the use of a text-mode VGA console. Use of other console
               drivers including, but not limited to, vesafb, may result in
               corruption and stability problems, and is not supported.


[    7.653726] VBoxPciLinuxInit
[    7.654634] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)


[   18.164053] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC1D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 5


[    2.741035] kvm: disabled by bios

[    2.171220] usb 1-9.4: SerialNumb
```

None of these seem to be catastrophic though the PCI & ACPI errors are a little troubling for me.

`inxi` reports my system as:

```
System:    Kernel: 4.13.0-19-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.2.0
           Desktop: Gnome 3.26.2 (Gtk 3.22.25-0ubuntu0.1) Distro: Ubuntu 17.10
Machine:   Device: desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: ROG MAXIMUS X HERO v: Rev 1.xx serial: N/A
           UEFI: American Megatrends v: 0213 date: 08/23/2017
Battery    hidpp__0: charge: N/A condition: NA/NA Wh model: Logitech Performance MX status: Discharging
CPU:       Hexa core Intel Core i7-8700K (-HT-MCP-) arch: Skylake rev.10 cache: 12288 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 44352
           clock speeds: max: 4700 MHz 1: 3700 MHz 2: 3700 MHz 3: 3700 MHz 4: 3700 MHz 5: 3700 MHz 6: 3700 MHz
           7: 3700 MHz 8: 3700 MHz 9: 3700 MHz 10: 3700 MHz 11: 3700 MHz 12: 3700 MHz
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB] bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.5 ) drivers: nvidia (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev,vesa,nouveau)
           Resolution: 2560x1440@59.95hz, 1680x1050@59.88hz
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB/PCIe/SSE2 version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 384.90 Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 NVIDIA GP106 High Definition Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 01:00.1
           Card-2 Intel 200 Series PCH HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1f.3
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.13.0-19-generic
Network:   Card: Intel Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k bus-ID: 00:1f.6
           IF: enp0s31f6 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 27.0C mobo: N/A gpu: 1.0:39C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: 0
Info:      Processes: 309 Uptime: 1:48 Memory: 2298.6/15966.5MB Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 7.2.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.4.121) inxi: 2.3.37
```

This is driving me insane, it is particularly troublesome in games but also quite irritating in the GUI.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be the USB driver. Changing to another USB port fixes the problem. Changing back to the USB group on the motherboard starts the problem again. Maybe the coffee-lake USB drivers are not that stable yet.